# Kubernetes : Force value of "$pvname" with nfs-client-provsisioner

Tags: kubernetes, nfs, persistent-volumes

I use nfs-client-provisioner inside my kubernetes cluster.

But, the name of the PersistentVolume is random.

cf. doc:
[nfs-client-provisioner](https://github.com/rimusz/nfs-client-provisioner)

> --> Persistent volumes are provisioned as ${namespace}-${pvcName}-${pvName}

But, where could i change the value of pvName ??

Actually, it's random, for exemple : pvName = pvc-2v82c574-5bvb-491a-bdfe-061230aedd5f

Answer (score 1):

This is the naming convention of directories corresponding to the `PV` names but stored on share of NFS server

If it comes to `PV` name provisioned dynamically by `nfs-provisioner` it follow the following naming convention:

`pvc-` + `claim.UID`

Background information:

According to the design proposal of external storage provisioners (NFS-client belongs to this category), you must not declare `volumeName` explicitly in [PVC spec](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/design-proposals/storage/volume-provisioning.md).

> #  volumeName: must be empty!

`pv.Name` **MUST** be unique. Internal provisioners use name based on `claim.UID` to produce conflicts when two provisioners accidentally provision a `PV` for the same claim, however external provisioners can use any mechanism to generate an unique `PV` name.

In case of `nfs-client` provisioner, the `pv.Name` generation is handled by the `controller` library, and it gets following format:

`pvc-` + `claim.UID`

[Source](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/sig-storage-lib-external-provisioner/blob/c525773885fccef89a1edd22bb3f813d50548ed1/controller/controller.go#L1414)

I hope it helps.